# Why am I able to bypass the has_one relationship with the << operator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Here's the example relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :group, through: :group_membership
    has_one :group_membership
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
  has_many :group_memberships
end

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Why am I able to do the following?

```
Group.first.users << User.first
Group.second.users << User.first
```

I would have thought the has_one relationship would have prevented this from happening.  Is there some magic behind the `<<` that I'm not aware of?

`User.first.group` will return the second group, but both groups get persisted.

Comment: `has_one` only returns one result. It doesn't prevent you from doing anything. It just might work in an unexpected way if you add more than one item to the association.

Comment: Are you? Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.2.0, I get a `NoMethodError`, as my model doesn't have `<<` defined at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `has_one` can only help you if you add to the `User` side of the association, ie. when you use the `has_one` method itself (where there's no `<<` defined).

The best way to get what you want here is to actually change the association so that it's a `belongs_to` on the `User` side. Then a `User` can only ever be associated with a single `Group`. You could achieve a similar thing with a unique DB index on the `user_id` field in the `group_memberships` table.

Comment: Adding the unique constraint to the DB was a great suggestion was a great suggestion.  Thanks!